# Webview rendering, Swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, webview

I'm trying to render different HTML in my web view. To give you a reference I would love to render html like an email client (where the html is perfectly resized in the screen).

This is my code:

```
 func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

    var jsScript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');"
    jsScript += "meta.name='viewport';"
    jsScript += "meta.content='width=device-width';"
    jsScript += "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"

    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jsScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

    let wkController = WKUserContentController()

    wkController.addUserScript(userScript)

    let wkWebConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    wkWebConfiguration.userContentController = wkController

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: wkWebConfiguration)

    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let htmlBody = htmlBody {
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlBody, baseURL: nil)
    }

    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

    return webView
}
```

This is working pretty fine, but sometimes I have some html that is rendered very small. I've found two scenarios during my investigation:

Problem 1 => Sometimes the html text is quite long, so the web view is adapted to this length and it turns out that everything is smaller. If I'm able to break long lines I think the html should render fine.

Problem 2 => Some html (a little amount) is rendered with some extra blank space even if I'm injecting the possibility to render the full screen. Because of this, the text is small.

I'm comparing this rendering with (for example) an email from Gmail where the html is perfect on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an IOS or WebView issue Email like the client is always a pain when it comes to CSS that can not be applied. To get better rendering you do not need anything to do on WebView but check out this [post](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding-html-emails/)

In mail clients CSS is not working the same way as it does on normal renders Browsers or mobile browsers, some CSS styles are not supported at all.

Also, this part of code will adjust WebView to fit your content which results in smaller elements

```html
 webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```